# query ordering problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a car model. (In my database, the **cars** table has a column named "**customer_id**".)

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

A customer model: (The **customer** model has a attribute named "**customer_name**".)

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end
```

My question is, if I queried the **cars** table with:

```
where("id >= ? AND id <= ?", 3, 15) #get some cars
```

Then I would like to order this result by **customer_name** ascending order, what's the ordering code??

I tried both

```
where("id >= ? AND id <= ?", 3, 15).order("customer_id.customer_name ASC")
```

and

```
where("id >= ? AND id <= ?", 3, 15).order("customer.customer_name ASC")
```

But seems neither of them is working. Any body can help? (I am using Rails 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `join` the custom table for this query to work.

Try

```
.joins(:customer).where("cars.id >= ? AND cars.id <= ?", 3, 15).order("customers.customer_name ASC")
```